# Where can I post my solution for "scrollable table with fixed headings"?

Tags: discussion

As I'm new in the forum, my question is: Is there some special place for posting programming solutions?

Comment: or here: [How can I create an advanced grid interface on Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21117/5478)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to Mathematica.SE and our Meta site for it (what you are reading now).

Do not mistake these sites for a normal discussion forum as they are not.  See [the tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) for a rundown.

If you have something that you believe will be of general interest it is entirely acceptable, even encouraged, to post a question and answer it yourself.  There is even a check-box in the interface to allow you to post both the question and answer at the same time.  See this question on our own Meta from the site's early days:

- [Posting a question you already know the answer for](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/46/121)

See this FAQ from the main (general) Stack Exchange Meta site:

- [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463)

Also related:

- [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845)